# Efficiently extracting a subset of a large file in python

Tags: python, list, file, numpy

I have a large file of a few million lines of text. I want to extract a smaller (250000 lines) from this file uniformly at random. I did the following code, but it is surprisingly very slow, actually unusably slow. What can I do to speed it up?

```
def get_shorter_subset(fname, new_len):
"""Extract a random shorter subset of length new_len from a given file"""
   out_lines = []
   with open(fname + "short.out", 'w') as out_file:
      with open(fname, 'r') as in_file:
        all_lines = in_file.readlines()
        total = len(all_lines)
        print "Total lines:", total
        for i in range(new_len):
            line = np.random.choice(all_lines)
            out_lines.append(line.rstrip('\t\r\n'))
            #out_file.write(line.rstrip('\t\r\n'))
            print "Done with", i, "lines"
            all_lines.remove(line)
      out_file.write("\n".join(out_lines))
```

Answer (score 2):

So, the issue:

`all_lines = in_file.readlines()` reads all the lines into memory probably not the best way to do this... but if you *are* going to do that, then **definitely don't do this**: `all_lines.remove(line)` because that is an O(N) operation, which you are doing in a loop, giving you quadratic complexity.

I suspect you will gain huge performance improvements by simply doing something to the effect of:

```
idx = np.arange(total, dtype=np.int32)
idx = np.random.choice(idx, size=new_len, replace=False)
for i in idx:
    outfile.write(all_lines[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use mmap:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/mmap.html

Answer (score 1):

You read in all of the lines, hold them in memory, and then perform 250K large-string operations on the the resulting text.  Every time you remove a line from the file, Python has to make a new copy of the remaining lines.

Instead, just take a random sample.  For instance, if you have 5 million lines, you want 5% of the file.  Read the file, one line at a time.  Roll a random float number.  If it's <= 0.05, write that line to the output.

With such a large sample, you'll end up with output of the desired size.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the Python numpy library. The [`numpy.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy-random-choice) function provides the functionality you need. It will take a sample of the lines up to the size you need in a single call. So your function would look like:

```
import numpy as np

def get_shorter_subset(fname, new_len):
    """Extract a random shorter subset of length new_len from a given file"""

    with open(fname + " short.out", 'w') as out_file, open(fname, 'r') as in_file:
        out_file.write(''.join(np.random.choice(list(in_file), new_len, False)))

get_shorter_subset('input.txt', 250000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, I did a solution to generate a random number (with probability corresponding to new_size/full_size) at each index and picking or discarding each element based on that. So the code is:

```
def get_shorter_subset(fname, new_len):
"""Extract a random shorter subset of length new_len from a given 
   file"""
   out_lines = []
   with open(fname + "short.out", 'w') as out_file:
       with open(fname, 'r') as in_file:
           all_lines = in_file.readlines()
           total = len(all_lines)

           freq = total/new_len + 1
           print "Total lines:", total, "new freq:", freq
           for i, line in enumerate(all_lines):
               t = np.random.randint(1,freq+1)
               if t == 1:
                   out_lines.append(line.rstrip('\t\r\n'))
               #out_file.write(line.rstrip('\t\r\n'))
               if i % 10000 == 0:
                   print "Done with", i, "lines"

       out_file.write("\n".join(out_lines))
```